# Spawn gem on heroku - "PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, spawn

I'm using the Spawn gem in a rails 3 app - it's the rails3-adapted fork at https://github.com/rfc2822/spawn

My app is deployed on heroku, and when i tried to spawn i get this failure:

```
 app[web.1]: ### ../controllers/messages_controller.rb:10:in `create_message': About to spawn
 app[web.1]: spawn> parent PID = 1
 app[web.1]: spawn> child PID = 49
 app[web.1]: ### ../controllers/messages_controller.rb:17:in `create_message': After spawn
 app[web.1]:   Task Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = 80 LIMIT 1
 app[web.1]: PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 app[web.1]:    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 app[web.1]:    before or while processing the request.
```

I have this option in my config/database.yml, following the recommendation of the spawn documentation:

```
reconnect: true
```

Is it connected to this do you think?

Bit at a loss with this... before i go investigating, does anyone know what's causing this?
cheers, max

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the girl_friday gem instead, which is a simple forked-queue system.  It worked great for me.